# _customer_script.sh: line 4: $: command not found

Tags: python, django, ibm-cloud

I am trying to push my application to Bluemix, however, I am getting this error:

```
stack: cflinuxfs2
buildpack: https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cf-buildpack-python.git#v1.5.1

state since cpu memory disk details   
#0   running   2016-05-27 10:16:28 AM   0.0%   90.8M of 1G   156.5M of 1G      
Sending deployment success of twhisper to IBM DevOps Services...
IBM DevOps Services notified successfully.
_customer_script.sh: line 4: $: command not found

Finished: ERRORED
```

More details about my application:
I am using Python 2.7.10 on Windows OS.

Manifest file:

```
applications:
- name: twhisper
  memory: 1024M
  command: python manage.py runserver
  buildpack: https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cf-buildpack-python.git#v1.5.1
  path: .
```

Requirements.txt:

```
Django==1.6.5
pygal==1.5.0
pymongo==2.8.0
cloudant==2.0.0a1
twitter==1.14.3
dj-database-url==0.3.0
django-cors-headers==1.0.0
xlwt==1.0.0
requests==2.7.0
```

Comment: Any chance you checked _customer_script.sh: line 4?

Comment: I do not have any idea where would i find ' _customer_script.sh: line 4: $ ' command in my application. Can you help me with that?